# Message created time in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

When I consume message in Kafka, how can I know when this message is produced/created?

```
There is no created method in MessageAndMetadata.
```

And How to set offset in Kafka when neccessary? I prefer setting by code or command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no per-message timestamping in Apache Kafka 0.7 or 0.8, but it would be handy.

What exists is a time-based offset-lookup in the Offset API:

> Time - Used to ask for all messages before a certain time (ms). There are two special values. Specify -1 to receive the latest offset (i.e. the offset of the next coming message) and -2 to receive the earliest available offset. Note that because offsets are pulled in descending order, asking for the earliest offset will always return you a single element.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-OffsetAPI

It relies on the filesystem ctime of the topic+partition segment files on the broker so it is a bit crude (depending on file rotation intervals, etc) and in the case of replication may be outright incorrect (timestamp of replication rather than when the original segment was created).

The solution is to embed the message creation time in the message itself.